# Is connected component of sublevel set of continuous function always path connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness, path-connected

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function. Let $S_a\triangleq \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\,|\,f(x)\leq a\}$ be a sublevel set of $f$. If $S_a$ is connected, is it always path-connected? If not, any counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ be closed and connected but not path connected (for example you can take as $A$ the $\sin(1/x)$-continuum, also called the topologist's sine curve).

Consider $f(x)=d(x,A)$ and look at $S_0$.

Comment: Thanks! I know an example of closed and connected but not path connected set, but just got stuck on sublevel set of continuous function. Very neat example!